# Can Mezzanine send an email to admin when a user signs up?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

Is there any way to configure Mezzanine so that the admin user gets an email when a new (regular) user signs up? I have `ACCOUNTS_VERIFICATION_REQUIRED=True`, so the would-be user gets an email, but I don't want to have to approve accounts myself (`ACCOUNTS_APPROVAL_REQUIRED`).

If this isn't possible out of the box, do I need to customize the `accounts` app? Or monkey-patch `UserProfileAdmin.save_model`? What is the best approach?

Comment: Don't know off the top of my head if there's an easier solution but before you go monkey-patching *any* `save_model` method in Django, consider using the `pre_save` or `post_save` signal instead. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of closure, here is the solution I was more or less handed from Steve MacDonald himself on the mezzanine-users mailing list. The setting [`ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_CLASS`](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html#accounts-profile-form-class) allows one to specify a custom form class for user profile signup/update. So, in `settings.py` set:

```
ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_CLASS = "myapp.forms.MyCustomProfileForm"
```

And in `myapp.forms.py` send the email on save:

```
from mezzanine.accounts.forms import ProfileForm

class MyCustomProfileForm(ProfileForm):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(MyCustomProfileForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._signup:
            # send email here
        return user
```

This worked very well for me.